# Apple Music API Reference

Tags: javascript, ios, api, apple-developer, apple-musickit

I'm trying to use Apple Music API to get users data (playlists, tracks, adding and creating playlists).

When following this guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/AppleMusicWebServicesReference/SetUpWebServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017625-CH2-SW1

I can't find the keys menu shown in the image : [image]

the screen i get is this : [image]

I'm not so sure if I need to enroll as a developer to get API access.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a profile/certificate to obtain your key you need to be a registered Apple Developer (paid subscription).

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait about 48 hours to activate the dev account